# Migrating ClearCase to TFS 2010 using TFS Integration Tool

Tags: migration, clearcase

I'm trying to migrate a ClearCase Server to TFS2010 using TFS Integration Tool, I have tried a lot of possible ways not getting the expected result. In TFS integration tool there is a field named Path that I can't figure it out what I should put in there to get it work. I tried to put the vob name of a project and a folder inside it, but when I start the migration nothing happens.

[image]

It suddenly stops, the logs are as follow:

[image]

If any one know the correct steps to make the migration or knows exactly what should I put in the Path field. Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a path of a *started* dynamic view (which select the right versions to import).

So you need to make sure:

- `cleartool startview a_dynamic_view_tag`
- select the drive `M:\` (default mounting point for dynamic view)
- add an existing path within `M:\a_dynamic_view_tag`: a mounted `vob/afolder` (if the vob isn't yet mounted: `cleartool mount \avobname`).
  Note: if you want to import the all vob, you could just put the name of the vob (again, it needs to be mounted first to be visible in the dynamic view).

Comment: Thanks @VonC, I'm trying what you told me, I also would like to ask if it works with a SnapShot view?

Comment: @yosoy not sure, unless you can enter the root path of that snapshot view (which you don't with a dynamic view, since *all* dynamic views are mounted on `M:` MVFS drive)

Comment: So, I put \dynamic_view_tag\mybov and it is working, I let you know if it does what it should.

Comment: thanks for the help. One question, is normal that the migration progress makes some Mkelem and Checkin? It does not affect my history in ClearCase? I used One-Way Migration.

Comment: @yosoy I am not familiar enough with that import process, but that should be on the TFS side.